# Выполнение действия через x времени

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Допустим, у меня есть две строки:
String a="abc";
String b="def";

Каким образом можно сделать чтобы строка b отобразилась спустя какое либо время (например 5 секунд) после отображения строки a, которая отобразится сразу при запуске программы?

Comment: Если вас помог ответим, плюсаните его, нажав стрелу вверх рядом с ним. Если он решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

P.S Полностью остановит программу, если она однопоточная.

Answer (score 2):

Есть метод sleep(long millis), который приостанавливает работу потока на время равное millis, время указывается в миллисекундах.

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "def";

System.out.println(a);
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println(b);
```

P.s. это не означает, что вывод второй строки будет ровно через 5 секунд, но будет близкое к этому значению.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите сделать паузу, используйте java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit:

```
 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

Чтобы спать в течение одной секунды или в течение 5 минут

```
  TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
```

Или 
      Thred Sleep

```
   try        
   {
   Thread.sleep(5000);
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) 
    {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

см. также официальную документацию https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep() вызовет Thread.sleep. Единственное различие - читаемость и использование TimeUnit, вероятно, легче понять для неочевидных длительностей